# isotope selected element control

Tags: css, jquery-isotope

I'm having a little trouble controlling the visual display of my filtering tabs and pagination links using Isotope. I want to fix two issues:

1 How do I class one of my filtering tabs so it looks already selected on page load?

2 When I click on a pagination link in the container, the currently selected tab is declassed, meaning it no longer looks selected?

Please see the demo here andym.ca/designs/isotope/tester4.html and you will understand what I mean.

Comment: Not very clear what you mean by "mark my initial filter clicked"... Do you want to say that, for example, the Archive Videos tab is already in dark grey and the corresponding videos are displayed - when a visitor visits your site first time? With these confusing dummy vid names, it's rather hard to understand your second question also. What exactly is not happening when using your three filter tabs on top of the Isotope container?

Comment: sorry i agree it wasnt the best laid out question. onload the first tab should have the selected class assigned to it.
The other issue is if you click on archive tab then click on the pagination, the archive tab class loses its dark grey selection class and gets added to the pagination selected classes instead, so i need the selected archive tab stay on when you are viewing the pagination links.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regarding the first question; before the code of your Isotope logic proper, you could have this anonymous self-executing function to preset certain things

```
(function(){
    var selector = $('.classtobefilteredoutonload');
    $container.isotope({ filter: selector });
    // other things that shall happen too go here, like assigning the right class to you PMTV tab div
    return false;
})();
```

Or failing that, leverage [hash history](http://isotope.metafizzy.co/docs/hash-history-jquery-bbq.html) to preset your site.

Regarding the second question, it looks like you're using this CngClass function to toggle the focus for all your clickable "a" elements, so naturally Archive Videos will lose focus when you click on a pagination "a" element. You can see it well in Google Chrome's developer tools while clicking on your tabs and paginators.

Well, you should toggle a "highlighting class" on your pagination separately, with a different function from the one that toggles your tabs. An anonymous self-executing function executes as soon as it is encountered, so it looks like the rest of your DOM is not ready. Try the same function but with on document ready.

You can do it [like this](http://jsfiddle.net/ckCfS/).

You can pre-mark your tab or whatever item on screen [like this](http://jsfiddle.net/ckCfS/2/)

Comment: that, i made your code change (pls view my example..all source is there) but it does seem to be taking effect (i changed the class to the appropriate style).

What would you suggest to use for the pagination so the style of the archive vids does not change upon click of any of the pagination buttons?

Comment: so i took away the CngClass function, but that leave me with the paginations hot showing any selected classes, any ways around this?

also after adding the script you gave, the animation was broken so i had to take it away, please view current version.

Comment: sorry, can you show me an example including my code, as i cant seem to get this working im afraid.

Comment: So, you got it now? Simple, uh?

Comment: thats perfect thanks you, my only issue now is having the first tab marked as selected when loaded...can you help?